# Is it possible to get two monsters of the same kind?

Tags: game-boy, dragon-warrior-monsters

It's an old game but I found it recently and I'm playing it now.

I got a monster, a Gremlin, which has a fire attack so I gave it to the guy near the bazaar with a grill (after which the grill transformed in a portal). I'd like to get another one but no matter how many times I go against one of its kind and the treats I'm throwing at it, it doesn't want to come with me.

Is it possible to *capture* two monsters of a kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I've done it many times. But once you got a monster, "capturing" another one of the same species becomes **much, much harder**. We're talking 1-2 Sirloins harder.

So basically, if you throw enough treats at it, it will follow you. Since the Gremlin you're trying to get is easily accessible early on, you can save, go into a portal, find a Gremlin and throw loads of meat onto it. If it still doesn't follow you, reset and try again. This "strategy" becomes a lot less viable later when you're trying to get another one of a monster available deep inside a portal (Metabbles, for example). Then, you will need to resort to that item that lets you save inside a Portal (Bookmark? not sure what it's called any more...).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The most expensive meat I have available are ribs, I guess sirloins came later on in the game; but I'll give that strategy a try.

Although I feel there's no way of having actually all the monsters at the same time, in the farm you can only have 2 batches of 19 in total. I think it's more about breeding to get better monsters.

Comment: @Carlo: Yes, they come later. And you're right, you can't have all of them at the same time, breeding plays a major role in DWM. You do get a little more space later on if I remember correctly, but it's still far from enough to get all Monsters. But the breeding system encourages getting rid of monsters anyway. Once you breed some, you really don't need the others any more. Stats, resistances and abilities are all passed on through breeding to some extent.